# Flutter error - type 'Future<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Widget'

Tags: flutter

need some help with some coding. I know createUserInFirestore() returns a Future() hence cannot be inserted into the widget build hence i get the error "type 'Future' is not a subtype of type 'Widget'".

I have tried using Futurebuilder but have not been successful.

Is anyone able to advise on how to integrate the future function into the widget. Thanks!

Code below:

```
class LandingPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LandingPageState createState() => _LandingPageState();
}

class _LandingPageState extends State<LandingPage> {
  final usersRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users');
  final DateTime timestamp = DateTime.now();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder(
        stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState != ConnectionState.active) {
            return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          }
          final user = snapshot.data;
          if (user == null) {
            print("user is not logged in");
            return LoginPage();
          } else {
            print("user is logged in");
            return createUserInFirestore();
          }
        });
  }

  createUserInFirestore() async {
    final user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
    final DocumentSnapshot doc = await usersRef.doc(user!.uid).get();
    if (!doc.exists) {
     
      final displayname = await Navigator.push(context,
          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => CreateDisplayName()));

     
      usersRef.doc(user.uid).set({
        "id": user.uid,
        "displayname": displayname,
        "photoUrl": user.photoURL,
        "email": user.email,
        "bio": "",
        "timestamp": timestamp
      });
    } else {
      return MainPage();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to return widget in both cases

```
Future<Widget> createUserInFirestore() async {
    final user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
    final DocumentSnapshot doc = await usersRef.doc(user!.uid).get();
    if (!doc.exists) {
     
      final displayname = await Navigator.push(context,
          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => CreateDisplayName()));

     
      usersRef.doc(user.uid).set({
        "id": user.uid,
        "displayname": displayname,
        "photoUrl": user.photoURL,
        "email": user.email,
        "bio": "",
        "timestamp": timestamp
      });
    return Container();
    } else {
      return MainPage();
    }
  }
```

Comment: I get an error: 31:20: Error: A value of type 'Future<Widget>' can't be returned from a function with return type 'Widget'.

Comment: you need to await it
var widget = await return createUserInFirestore();
return widget;